# Excel: hover preview over excel image link

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, helper

I'm trying to display an image which is located at the cloud service at the excel file.
Are there any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: You need `VBA` to show image from web.

Comment: @Harun24HR how can i do that? Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Right now I am on hurry. So can't explain. You can just check this sample file [Sample File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ohRFzRy6bqwTD_n8Zsa82ewxhiJEuuQm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Harun24HR reset function isn't working